# Why does TS not load my npm link'ed class on runtime only?

Tags: typescript, npm

I used `create-react-app` with TypeScript setup to create my app boilerplate, did not change `tsconfig.json` after that. I have some code outside of my src directory, so to use it I used `npm link`, thus it's available in my local `node_modules` through a symlink.

Here's the class in question:

```ts
import { AuthState } from '../DataTypes/AuthState'

export class AuthFilters {
  constructor(private authState: AuthState) {}

  signedIn() {
    return this.authState.isSignedIn
  }

  guest() {
    return !this.signedIn()
  }
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to use it:

```ts
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Header, HeaderStateProps, HeaderDispatchProps } from './Header'
import { AuthFilters } from 'shared/Functions/AuthFilters'
import { AppState } from '../../redux/root'

export const HeaderContainer = connect<HeaderStateProps, HeaderDispatchProps>(
  (state: AppState) => ({
    // other props
    authFilters: new AuthFilters(state.auth)
  })
)(Header)
```

It seems like everything should work, neither the linter nor the compiler don't throw any errors, but here's what happens at runtime:

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_shared_Functions_AuthFilters**.AuthFilters is not a constructor

In fact, when I try to `console.log(AuthFilters)` in `HeaderContainer` it is `undefined`. Another question that I found says that such errors can be caused when you use the `--outFile` parameter of the compiler and don't put imports in the right order. However, since I didn't set up the compiler, I'm not sure how and where exactly to check the compiler options, or what order the imports should be in...

Just in case, here's my `tsconfig.json`, it has no mention of `outFile`:

```ts
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Update:** I tried to move the `shared` folder physically into the project, it did not fix the issue. Weirdly though, when extracted the folder's contents into the `src` directory, it started working...

That means that it works when instead of importing `./shared/Functions/AuthFilters` it imports `./Functions/AuthFilters`.

Comment: Does not seem to be TypeScript error as it compiles fine. The problem seems to be with webpack which doesn't know about your symlink.

Comment: Well, webpack compiles it without issues, and it has a reference to it in the compiled files. At the very least, it should be a string - path to the file, but not undefined

Comment: webpack complete its bundle process does not mean it bundles it correctly. You get `undefined` precisely because webpack can't resolve the file and bundle the file in correctly.

Comment: I just tried to physically move the file and unfortunately the error persists...